# GWT:How to close the session on closing the browser

Tags: gwt

In my GWT application i am trying to clear the session if browser closed by user .

what i am doing is on closing Handler calling the rpc which invalidate the session,
but the rpc call never happened and browser get closed.
if there's any other solution for this

```
  Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {

            signOut();
        }

        });

  public void signOut() {
    rpcService.signOut(new AsyncCallback<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {

            History.newItem("login");
        }});
}

   public String signOut(){
    session = request.getSession();
    session.invalidate();
    return "loggedout";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. try with

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {

               }
        });
```

AFAIK Don't use `Window.addWindowClosingHandler` because it will also call even you close popup. The `Window.addCloseHandler' called when browser closed.

Comment: tried , same beehavior ..it reaches to signOut method but RPC call never made, console says: 
Remote connection lost

Comment: I have implemented same feature and it's work. can you put some wait call after `signOut();` method called. then check what happen.

Comment: you mean u able to call the RPC , and RPC get success and AFTER that your browser get closed ?

Comment: no it will never happened.  as you know RPC call is async. you never get success call then window close. it will close before completed rpc.but it's reaches to server. right? we don't have worried about client session. I just have to clear server session. then if user again open same app. then one call should be there which will check server session is exist or not. if there then direct redirect to home page other wise login page and create new session.

Comment: in my case its not even reaching to server

Comment: that is why I am telling put some wait call using timer after signOut() method. then check.

Comment: @junaidp then I don't know. you have to look out for rpc call. if same rpc call works other then it should work here.